# How to fetch an id with mapping column in criteria builder

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I hava a One table which is name on association and the table have 3 column which is id,settings,creation.
The settings is mapping with Set and creation is mapping with create in Entity class.
Set contains set_id,set_edit and create contains create_id and create_name.

When I put on the sql query it will be execute the result fine.
"SELECT count(create_id) FROM `association` where `set_id`= X'143d3149791c4dd7b4ae08a7074c69d2'"

but how to use criteria builder in hibernate.

Actually what I want means,pass a parameter of set_id to search the db and get the linking create_id count with the association table, but it is mapping on creative then how to get the create_id in criteria builder using spring boot

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. "I hava a One table which is name on association" makes no sense at all. Can you please clarify? Posting your database schema and the Hibernate entities would also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<AdGroupCreativeAssociation> query = builder.createQuery(AdGroupCreativeAssociation.class);
    Root<AdGroupCreativeAssociation> root = query.from(AdGroupCreativeAssociation.class);
    query.select(root.get("id"));
    TypedQuery<AdGroupCreativeAssociation> q = session.createQuery(query);
    List<AdGroupCreativeAssociation> list =  q.getResultList().stream().filter(
            i -> ((i.getAdsets().getAdsetId().compareTo(adsetId) == 0)
                    && (i.getCreative().getCreativeid()
                            .compareTo(creativeId) == 0)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<UUID> resultList = list.stream().map(i -> i.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return resultList;
```